# how to show parameter value on report in rdlc and vb,net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, rdlc

i am developing small project with vb.net and sql server.now i want to create report.i am using rdlc report.i created report and set parameters and now i want to show selected parameter value in report header.i try several thing but none of them worked for me.this is my currunt code.

```vb
Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms

Public Class meberwisepayment
    Private Sub meberwisepayment_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub find_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles find.Click
        Me.mpaymentTableAdapter.Fill(Me.eksath1DataSet.mpayment, fromdate.Text, todate.Text)
        Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()


    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: That code is completely useless because it doesn't show you trying anything.  Do your research, implement what you think you need to and then, if it doesn't work, show us what you did and tell us exactly what it does do.  For a start, have you actually added parameters to your report in the designer?

Comment: i add 2 datetime pickers to pass the dates

Comment: and write query in dataset with where condition and declare 2 parameters

Comment: then run the report and its works fine.but i want to show in selected date range in my report

Comment: but i am not add parameters in report designing view

Comment: Well then, that would be your problem. The fact that you used some values as filters in a query that populated a `DataTable` that was used as the data source for a report has exactly zero relevance to the report. It doesn't know or care how that `DataTable` came to be populated.  If you want to know how to pass values other than the data source into a report, do some research on that.  Asking a question here should be your last option, after you've done that research, not your first option instead of that research.

Answer (score 0):

finelly i got the answer

```
 Private Sub find_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles find.Click
    Me.mpaymentTableAdapter.Fill(Me.eksath1DataSet.mpayment, fromdate.Text, todate.Text)
    Dim ftital(1) As ReportParameter
    ftital(0) = New ReportParameter("fromdate", Me.fromdate.Value)
    ftital(1) = New ReportParameter("todate", Me.todate.Value)
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(ftital)
    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
End Sub
```